# How to test async handleSubmit(e) in react with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I want to test the submitting of a form in `jest`.
the forms `onSubmit` is linked to `handleSubmit(e)` which is an `async` method (it checks to see if username is already in use).

Does anyone know how I can test the onSubmit?

**Register.js**

```
class AddItems extends Component {

  async checkForErrors() {
    ...
    const usernameValid = await this.checkIfUsernameIsValid(this.state.username);
    ...

  async handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const err = await this.checkForErrors();
    ...

  render() {
    ...
    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
```

**Register.test.js**

```
fetch.mockResponse(JSON.Stringify({result: true}); //username is valid
//fill in the form-fields
form.simulate('submit');
expect(fetch.mock.calls[1]).toContainEqual('/users/register');
```

the `fetch.mock` only has 1 call; to `/users/validUsername`.
I know you can use await in jest, but not on `onSubmit` if `onSubmit` itself has no `async`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried these -

(copied from https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html)

```
test('the data is peanut butter', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  await expect(fetchData()).resolves.toBe('peanut butter');
});

test('the fetch fails with an error', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  await expect(fetchData()).rejects.toMatch('error');
});
```

Comment: I did it like this: await instance.handleSubmit({preventDefault() {}});  
But I'd still prefer to simulate the form.submit event